# How to remove a map key when key and value are reseral

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

everybody. I have a problem that I want to remove a key in a map when the map contains a reversal value, the code below:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put(0, 1);
test.put(1, 0);
test.put(2, 1);
test.put(3, 2);
```

IN the above code, you can see 0-1 and 1-0, but I just want to exist only one on the map like 0-1 or 1-0. Therefore I must remove one or more to keep only one stay on the map. In this case, the result should be like 0,1 and 2,1. I mean in this case, the result retains two-element on the map. Can someone help me that I very much appreciate it.

Comment: Which one of each pair do you want to keep? What does 'reseral' mean?

Comment: What is your use case?  To _implement_ this, you would almost have to have a map with each direction of the mapping, as you have now.  So the question is probably actually "how do I use this map in this way."

Comment: The reversal means if key and value are reversal that contains in the map . like data below: 
1,2; 2,1 in this case, key and value are reversal. Only one keep in but without specific. 1,2 is correct and also 2,1 is correct

Comment: Thank you for answer, Actually, I have a problem but it may be difficult to describe, So I just extract the problem that I felt should be fixed with this mapping problem.

Comment: for starter why not use for loop? then try aggregate operations.

Comment: Just iterate over the entries: for each entry, if the map contains the value as another key remove the current entry *via the iterator*.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom filter method to only preserve distinct elements. Keeping it generic for all types, it could be something like this:

```
public static <T,E> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, E> keyExtractor)
{
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return element -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(element), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

Because we need to check if both elements are present, but there order is of no importance, we could (ab)use a Set to create some kind of composite key where ordering is unimportant. You could also create your own Object here, with a customized equals/hashCode so that we don't need the `Set` anymore

### Full code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
    test.put(0, 1);
    test.put(1, 0);
    test.put(2, 1);
    test.put(3, 2);

    Map<Integer, Integer> uniques = test.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(distinctByKey(entry -> Set.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> entry.getValue()));

    System.out.println(uniques);
}

public static <T,E> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, E> keyExtractor)
{
    Map<Object, Boolean> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    return element -> map.putIfAbsent(keyExtractor.apply(element), Boolean.TRUE) == null;
}
```

### Result

```
{0=1, 2=1, 3=2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> filtered = new HashMap<>();
for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : test.entrySet()) {
    if(!Objects.equals(e.getKey(), filtered.get(e.getValue()))) {
        filtered.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

---

Here's another snippet, although I would prefer the first one.

```java
Map<Integer, Integer> filtered2 = new HashMap<>();
test.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if(!Objects.equals(k, filtered2.get(v))) {
        filtered2.put(k, v);
    }
});
```